# How to add flashable zip contents to aosp build

Tags: android

I want to include this flashable .zip file:

[image]

to my aosp build. I already placed priv-app to `packages/apps/here` with .mk file in each. I dont know where to place the others. There's also one `build.prop` addon file in the zip.